# Ancestry of Struckers in "The Gifted"

Tags: marvel, the-gifted

Are the Struckers in "**The Gifted**" television series related to Baron Wolfgang von Strucker? Like his descendants or it's just a coincidence.

***PS:*** I just started watching the series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the episode "threat of eXtinction", we learn that the father, Reed Strucker, is the grandson of [Andreas von Strucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenris_(comics)).  There was no mention of how Andreas and his twin relate to other characters in the Marvel Universe.

However, Hydra and Baron Strucker are intellectual properties of the MCU/Disney while X-men & mutants are Fox properties.  That means that any further tie probably won't be made apparent.  Most likely it will be treated like [Deadpool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PA5gSKKelV4) where the links are not expressly stated, but rather implied.

**UPDATE:** With Disney's recent [acquisition of much of Fox](https://www.polygon.com/2017/12/14/16778224/disney-fox-deal-movies-tv-rights), an X-Men/MCU crossover is back on the table.  It may now be possible that Baron von Strucker is tied to the other 4 generations of the Strucker family shown in the TV show.  I would guess not until season 2 or later, though.

Comment: Minor correction, the characters, as intellectual properties, all belong to Marvel. The rights to depict them on screen are what is split.
Also worth noting that in the comics, Andreas is the son of Wolfgang

Comment: Andreas and Andrea Strucker have been most prominent in the various Marvel mutant-related comics. While their father (there) is Baron Wolfgang von Strucker, it would make sense that they would be explicitly included in the list of characters Fox has/had exclusive rights to portray in movies and TV. However, it's less likely the Baron was in that list, as he has had relatively little impact on the mutant books - he was generally seen in S.H.I.E.L.D.-related books, or *CAPTAIN AMERICA*. It's possible he would have been available to both Fox and Disney (like Quicksilver was).

Answer (score -1):

Well this might not help but in the 1998 film nick fury agent of shield it shows that the baron in that film was born the same year as Andreas and Andrea in gifted so if they were sibling that be cool it also show that it is tradition to name twins in the family Andreas and Andrea cause we see a young Andrea in x2 wich is in the old timeline and could be the daughter of Otto strucker and in nick fury agent of shield barons children are Andrea and Werner showing that she has a twin that is most likely dead and we find out she secretly viper so she probably died also and that movie was distributed by fox and they also had to borrow name rights from fox for Andrea. What was I talking about.

Comment: And what if in the original timeline reed is Andreas the 3rd